# Selection sort on singly linked list. First element not moving

Tags: sorting, linked-list

my algorithm works. Atleast almost. For some reason first element not moving. Everything else sorts fine. Any ideas why it doesn't working?

```
public void sortSelection() {

        Node<E> e1 = first;

        while (e1!=null)
        {

            Node<E> e2 = first.next;

            while (e2!=null)
            {

                if (e2.element.compareTo(e1.element)<0)
                {

                    E temp = e1.element;
                    e1.element = e2.element;
                    e2.element = temp ;

                }

                e2 = e2.next;

            }

            e1 = e1.next ;

        }
}
```

Comment: make e2 as e1.next instead of first.next

Comment: Thank you. Working perfectly.